# WTForms doesn't validate MAC address

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm using WTForms' `MacAddress` validator, but it doesn't recognize valid MAC addresses that I enter.  Why isn't it working?

```
{'choice': [u'Invalid Mac address.']}
```

```
class EditForm(Form):
    choice = TextField('choice', validators=[DataRequired(), MacAddress()])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def devicechoice():
    form = EditForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print form.choice.data
        return redirect(url_for('editdevice'))
    else: 
        print form.errors

    return render_template('devicechoice.html', form=form)
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.choice() }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How do you format the mac addresses that you're passing ? `MacAddress` seems to validate addresses where fragments are joined with `:` c.f. [source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/validators.py#L364)

Comment: @Ketouem, That works, Thank you, Can't believe I forgot to try that

Comment: Great ;-) don't forget to mark this is question as resolved (including the solution to your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been answered by @Ketouem, Simply putting a ":" after every 2 characters of the Mac address validates the form. (12:34:56:78:AB:CD)